# Radius of Convergence of Complex Series: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 4^{n}(z-i-5)^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Find the radius of convergence of the following complex series and the complex point, where the center of the disk of convergence is located

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 4^{n}(z-i-5)^{2n}$$
My attempt:

I gather than $5+i$ is the center of the disk of convergence? Am a bit lost after that.

Comment: Write it in the geometric form $\sum r^n$ and use the fact that this converges if and only if $|r|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence works for complex series as for real ones. You have the right center of your disk. Now make a substitution to get a  power series.

At first you define $u=(z-i-5)^2$ 
So you have $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 4^n u^n$$
Obviously the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{4}$ for $u$. Taking the root, gives you the radius of convergence for $z$ which means you will get $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Let u = 5+i, then series is

4^n(z-u)^2n

And I can use the ratio test with this to get,

|4(z-u)^2| < 1

What do I do to drop the absolute values?

Comment: Oh I see. 
|z-(5+i)|^2 < 1/4 

would be the answer
and the radius being sqrt(1/4) = 1/2

Comment: yeah exactly :)